# How to add horizontal scrollbar to bootstrap-table?

Tags: javascript, jquery, frontend, bootstrap-table

I am facing problem in bootstrap table where I have columns that doesn't fit in screen so I want to handle that in bootstrap-table by giving horizontal scrollbar there.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can wrap the table in a `div` using class `.table-responsive`:

```html
<div class="table-responsive">
  <table class="table">
    ...
  </table>
</div>
```

Reference:
[Bootstrap 4.1 Table](https://getbootstrap.com/docs/4.1/content/tables/)

Comment: Not working and horizontal scroll is not visible, Is there any way to show horizontal scrollbar

Comment: It should be work, the class contains "overflow-x: auto", make sure the width of table is more than the ".table-responsive".

Answer (score 1):

You can use bootstrap provided classes to achieve this:

```html
<div>
  <div class="table-responsive">
    <table class="table table-striped table-bordered" style="width: 800px;">
      <tr>-</tr>
    </table>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Not working and horizontal scroll is not visible, Is there any way to show horizontal scrollbar

Answer (score 1):

just wrap the BootstrapTable inside div

```
<div className="table-responsive">
  <BootstrapTable responsive  ....  />
</div>
```